# SSIS: merging data from two csv's

Tags: ssis

I am importing data from csv file(csv1) having columns userid, date and focus. there are multiple records of same userid having diferrent focus value and different dates. i need to pick focus of the user id having latest date and join it with another file (csv2) having userid( more than one same userid)fisrtname lastname and focus.

The result should be that in csv 2 all same userid must have focus set to that of latest focus in csv1 file.

Can someone help how to achieve this result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but it takes 2 steps:

Step 1: Import csv2 (look-up table) into temporary table.

Step 2: Using SSIS, from "Data Flow Transformations" toolbox select "Lookup" item. Write a query to select data from temporary table. Define matching columns.

Also, there is "Merge Join" type of transformation, but it seems to me that you need "Lookup".

If you are not familiar with SSIS transformations, google for "ssis lookup transformation".

Answer (score 0):

1. For CSV 1 & 2, use Aggregate  transformation to  get  max date. Output  of the transformation is unique records with latest table
2. Merge join CSV 1 & 2 , fetch desired columns from  two input.